# value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and django. I was trying to make a todo app but i got error in my date field. I've tried searching in google for solutions but I couldn't get a solution for my problem.

models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.

```
def demo(request):
    task1 = `Task.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('task', '')
        priority = request.POST.get('priori`ty', '')
        date = request.POST.get('date', '')
        task = Task(name=name, priority=priority, date=date)
        task.save()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'task1': task1})

    # def details(request):

    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'task': task})
```

Comment: What do you do that causes this error? How do you enter the date? Is it a text input or a date picker?

Comment: It's a date picker.When I try to pick a date and submit, I end up in this error

Comment: Please show the template with the form with the date picker. In general, you should create a [mcve] that shows enough code to recreate the problem you are asking about. You should [edit] your question to explain the steps you perform that results in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a date format problem. Note that we don't see the left of the error message, that's where it shows what's causing it.

In the view, below the next line:

```
date = request.POST.get('date', '')
```

the following could work:

```
formatted_date = None if date == '' else datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') # (ISO-8601) Replace with the appropiate format
```

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the model, the date could be null, in which case, depending on the date returned by the request, if it is null, it returns an empty string. But django accepts None, but not "".

[models.DateField](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11765)

Comment: I had the same problem even before null setting to true.So I searched for solutions and found setting null=True will set it right.Still not working.